# Binding to a Grid Width in a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, data-binding, grid, styles, resourcedictionary

I have a text box in a grid, the textbox has a style applied to it in which I am trying to bind the width to the colum width in the grid.

window.xaml

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Register User" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
    <Label Content="User Name: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>


    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

DefaultStyle.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LabelStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{<!--?????????--!>}"/>
</Style>
```

I have tried a few thing but can't work out how to bind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the Width, just set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
```